# Live DVD's will not boot

Tags: installation, boot, hp, livedvd

I have a brand new HP Envy 17-j020us Core i7 w/Win8 laptop that I cannot boot on any live DVD. I,ve tried 12.04,12.10 and 13.04. I've tried Secure boot off and on, Legacy boot off and on. Grub loads fine but the screen goes black after selecting "Try" or "Install". DVD runs for several minutes but video never appears. I suspect a video problem on boot but it could be anything? I have a rough idea how to edit boot options in grub but I dont know what those video options would be? Any help is greatly appreciated.
EDIT: found another post similar that mentions option"nomodeset", will try that when I get home tonight. Other post however mention my intel HD4600 graphics being supported, so my initial thought of it being video related seems unlikely.
EDIT: Boot disks were turning screen brightness to ZERO! This is known bug from what I've read? And its on all three versions...12.04-12.10-13.04. Now If I can figure out how to mark this solved///

HP Envy 17-j020us